# Edge Animate Change SVG Image on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, svg, adobe-edge

I am new to Edge Animate and JavaScript as well.  I have a map and currently I have text displaying or colors changing as the moues moves over a specific country.  What I want to happen is when the I mouseover the country I would like for the image to pop-out and enlarge.  So for example when I mouseover France France becomes larger and a different color and then when the mouse leaves the larger France area the map returns to the original map.  Is this possible?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to use to make the change.     'sym.getSymbol('map').css({'background-image':'url("images/france_big.svg")'});

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use following fast trick:

1. Create "france_default" layer.
2. Create "france_mouse_over" layer.
3. On mouseover hide "france_default" layer.